# efficient way of doing matrix addition in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have many matrices to add. Let's say that the matrices are [M1, M2..., M_n]. Then, a simple way is

```
X = np.zeros()
for M in matrices:
    X += M
```

In the operation, X += M, does Python create a new memory for X every time += is executed? If that's the case, that seems to be inefficient. Is there any way of doing an in-place operation without creating a new memory for X?

Comment: What exactly do you have as : `[M1, M2..., M_n]`? Is it a list of arrays? Add a sample of it?

Comment: @Divakar I think it's a list of matrices.

Comment: @Divakar, M is np.ndarray.

Comment: I meant `[M1, M2..., M_n]`, which seems to be `matrices`. If it's a list of arrays, the posted solution would work.

Comment: @Divakar Right. But, what if M_i are given one by one sequentially? I am now implementing the gradient descent algorithm and each M_i is a gradient matrix. When I used +=, I wondered whether it would hurt the efficiency.

Comment: Stick to your code.

Answer (score 1):

This works but is not faster on my machine:

```
numpy.sum(matrices, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you get MemoryError, trying to second guess memory usage in numpy is not worth the effort.  Leave that to the developers who know the compiled code.

But we can perform some time tests - that's what really matters, doesn't it?

I'll test adding a good size array 100 times.

```
In [479]: M=np.ones((1000,1000))
```

Your iterative approach with +=

```
In [480]: %%timeit 
     ...: X=np.zeros_like(M)
     ...: for _ in range(100): X+=M
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 627 ms per loop
```

Or make an array of size (100, 1000, 1000) and apply `np.sum` across the first axis.

```
In [481]: timeit np.sum(np.array([M for _ in range(100)]),axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.54 s per loop
```

and using the `np.add` ufunc.  With `reduce` we can apply it sequentially to all values in a list.

```
In [482]: timeit np.add.reduce([M for _ in range(100)])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.53 s per loop
```

The `np.sum` case gives me a MemoryError if I use `range(1000)`.  I don't have enough memory to hold a (1000,1000,1000) array.  Same for the `add.reduce`, which builds an array from the list.

What `+=` does under the cover is normally hidden, and of no concern to us - usually.  But for a peak under covers look at `ufunc.at`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy.ufunc.at

> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand ‘a’ for elements specified by ‘indices’. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to a[indices] += b, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once.

So `X+=M` does write the sum to a buffer, and then copies that buffer to `X`.  There is a temporary buffer, but final memory usage does not change.
But that buffer creation and copying is done in fast C code.

`np.add.at` was added to deal with the case where that buffered action creates some problems (duplicate indices).

So it avoids that temporary buffer - but at a considerable speed cost.    It's probably the added indexing capability that slows it down.  (There may be a fairer `add.at` test; but it certainly doesn't help in this case.)

```
In [491]: %%timeit 
     ...: X=np.zeros_like(M)
     ...: for _ in range(100): np.add.at(X,(slice(None),slice(None)),M)
1 loop, best of 3: 19.8 s per loop
```