# Numpy - transform a numpy function into generator

Tags: python, performance, numpy, generator

I have a numpy function that convert a 2D array of x,y coordinates into a flat array of distance of each coordinates between the previous. (see [Numpy - transform 2D array of x,y coordinates into flat array of distance between coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892993/numpy-transform-2d-array-of-x-y-coordinates-into-flat-array-of-distance-betwee/))

```
input = [[-8081441,5685214], [-8081446,5685216], [-8081442,5685219], [-8081440,5685211], [-8081441,5685214]]
output = [-8081441, 5685214, 5, -2, -4, -3, -2, 8, 1, -3]
```

Thanks to [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893149/1914034), I have two numpy functions that is doing what I want

```
arr = np.asarray(input).astype(int)
np.hstack((arr[0], (-np.diff(arr, axis=0)).ravel()))
```

Another approach with slicing to replicate the differentiation -

```
arr = np.asarray(input).astype(int)
np.hstack((arr[0], (arr[:-1,:] - arr[1:,:]).ravel()))
```

**My question, is there a way to transpose one of these numpy function into a generator to improve performance? Is it possible to use numpy in a generator?**

Comment: First, beware of premature optimization, you have a function that does what you want. Second, generators really wont help you here. Numpy functions obtain much of their speed from vectorization which requires dense representation and essentially operates on all elements of an array simultaniously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python generator is a spinoff of lists.

```
In [207]: [i*2 for i in range(3)]
Out[207]: [0, 2, 4]
In [208]: (i*2 for i in range(3))
Out[208]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0xb6a1ffbc>
In [209]: list(_)
Out[209]: [0, 2, 4]
```

You could think of it as a lazy list.  It doesn't actually evaluate the elements until you iterate through it.  In Py3 `range` is a generator (`xrange` in Py2).  The `In[208]` line sets up a generator, but doesn't evaluate anything.  So it is fast. But iterating over it in [209] takes just as long as the original at [207].  (Well there might be minor differences.)

Thus a generator lets you think in blocks as you with lists, without creating all the intermediate lists.  It's more of a code organization tool than a performance one.

I can't think of anything equivalent when working with numpy arrays.

```
arr=np.array(input)  # creates fixed size array from input list
-np.diff(arr, axis=0)   # create another array
```

This creates a number of intermediate arrays, even a list, and ends up returning an array (and discarding the intermediates):

```
np.hstack((arr[0],(-np.diff(arr, axis=0)).ravel()))
```

There are a number of simple building blocks in that expression.  Numpy's speed comes from performing those steps in fast compiled code.  To get better speed you'd have to rewrite the problem in C or Cython.  In that code you can iterate, and perform complex operations at each step.

Conceivably numpy could perform some sort of lazy evaluation, but that would require major lowlevel coding.  And there's no guarantee that it would result in performance improvements.

I looked at the issue of intermediate buffers, and whether `add.at` improved performance (it doesn't) at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688879/901925

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally the most performant function is using an iterator in a generator (see [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/147908/68343)). Numpy functions above were significantly slower for processing multiple large arrays of coordinates.